# Show data in current day, week, month and year

Tags: php, mysql

I have table `user`, it contains `id_user`, `username` and `user_time`. And `user_time` is the time a user registered, the properties is `timestamp` so the output is like this:

```
User A | user_time > 2014-12-22 10:10:10
```

Then I use this query to display data per year

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_time = YEAR(NOW());
```

The query works but just returns an empty row. It's not only the year, but also day, week, and month return empty rows. Why is this query not returning any data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem is that you doesn't do anything with your data:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_time=YEAR(NOW())
```

Try to get the `YEAR` from the `user_time` too, like this, so you do compare the numbers, not `timestamp` and a number:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE YEAR(user_time) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Or, as @ItsMe suggested:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM user WHERE YEAR(user_time) = YEAR(NOW())
```

And please, avoid the `*` in your queries, this is a bad practice.

Comment: YEAR(user_time) = YEAR(NOW()) is not recommended; as it will require full table scan. Try `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM user WHERE YEAR(user_time) = YEAR(NOW())`

Answer (score 7):

`YEAR` returns a number like `2014`. That will never be equal to a time. You need to test whether the year of `user_time` is the same as the given year:

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE YEAR(user_time) = YEAR(NOW())
```